# Userdefined objects and ExcelIntegration

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, excel-dna

I am coding C# (Visual Studio Express 2012) and using ExcelIntegration. I want to let an `ExcelFunction` return a user defined object to a cell. And I further want an `ExcelFunction` take a userdefined object as input.

Here is an example of my code. This does not work, neither of the functions (`CreateDog` or `GetName`) are visible from Excel.

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public Dog(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public readonly string Name;
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        [ExcelFunction]
        public static Dog CreateDog(string name)
        {
            return new Dog(name);
        }

        [ExcelFunction]
        public static string GetName(Dog dog)
        {
            return dog.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

---

After Answer from yesterday I added a Dictionary. I have modified the code as below. This works. My question now is how to make this generic. Can I modify the ExcelDNA code somehow to do this dictionary stuff automatically for me?

namespace ExcelIntegration
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public Dog(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

```
    public readonly string Name;
}

public class TestClass
{
    static Dictionary<string, Dog> DogStore;

    [ExcelFunction]
    public static string CreateDog(string name)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog(name);
        string key = dog.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (DogStore.ContainsKey(key) == false) DogStore.Add(key, dog);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            DogStore = new Dictionary<string, Dog>();
            if (DogStore.ContainsKey(key) == false) DogStore.Add(key, dog);
        }
        return key;
    }

    [ExcelFunction]
    public static string GetName(string dogKey)
    {
        Dog dog = DogStore[dogKey];
        return dog.Name;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) does not yet have this kind of custom marshaling or object support built in. Depending on what you need, it might be as simple as adding some wrappers and conversion functions and an object dictionary to your code, or you might need to generate all the wrappers dynamically and register the new functions at runtime.

[Cubicle Tools](https://cubicle.codeplex.com/) is a recent (open-source) project that adds an extensive distributed object and code model on top of Excel-DNA. But that's a fairly complicated project to get your head around.

There's a very simple F#-based implementation of an object handler on top of the RTD mechanism described [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_thread/thread/138bc83923701e6d). (But that code can be made much nicer with the current Excel-DNA version.)

If you're just looking for some guidance, and your 'Dogs' are not too finicky, then the [Excel-DNA Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna) is probably the best place for a discussion.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for answer. I modified the code to add a dictionary (edited my original post with the updated code). I few follow up questions:

1. Can I make this generic? Can I modify ExcelDNA to do this for me?
2. If I create a lot of Dogs then this might explode in memory I guess. There is actually no need to save history of Dogs in the same cell. Can this be done in some smart way?

Comment: Because your key changes every time, every recalc of your function will make a new Dog. Is the name not enough to identify a unique Dog?